# ReplaceOne if query matches, InsertOne if document does not exist

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database-migration

I'm trying to write a data migration script with pymongo that would

1. ReplaceOne if `{'_id': id, 'array.0':{'$exists':False} }` matches
2. InsertOne if a document with the given `id` does not exist i.e. do **not** check for `'array.0':{'$exists':False}`

Currently the script is something like this

```
from pymongo import ReplaceOne

def replace_one(row, id):
    return ReplaceOne({'_id': id, 'array.0':{'$exists':False} }, row, upsert=True)
```

This may lead to a duplicate key error since the `upsert=True` makes it to try to create a document if the query does not match and a document with the query's id already exists. But I want to create the document only if the document does not exist before.

Another requirement is that I don't want to use update since it is much slower when you have plenty of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like you are using the bulk operators.

What you need to use is `UpdateOne()`, and then on your bulk write add the `ordered=False` parameter. This will attempt the update but any errors (i.e. duplicate errors) are ignored.

There's no reason why `UpdateOne` would be slower than the `ReplaceOne` in your example.

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations

Comment: Thanks! The `ordered=False` did the trick. I still prefer using ReplaceOne though :p